# International order/donation failing in CartThrob but settling correctly in Authorize.net

Tags: cartthrob, shopping-cart, authorize.net

We're having a strange thing happening in CartThrob. We've set it things up to allow people to make donations (one-time or monthly) on the site.

In one particular instance, a donor from Germany attempted to make a donation but CT/EE gave her an error:

> "Payment failed, unspecified error"

In the backend, the error is as so:

[image]

This wouldn't be an issue except that Authorize.net processed the transaction successfully:

[image]

I'm not sure what would cause this to happen. The donation form is set up to take international info, but maybe I missed something?

Here's what that code looks like: http://pastie.org/private/5kpouwclti1gtkguvdvd7w

Any ideas or suggestions would be helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm with Vector; we're the people behind CartThrob)

Angie ended up submitting a ticket to us, and it turned out to be over-aggressive fraud settings on the credit card gateway's side. The payments were getting held for review.